# Removing Duplicates from array of object and merging it's Subarray into one

Tags: node.js, merge, duplicates, grouping

I am having an array of Objects with a Data index as subarray in it.The array of objects is returning Duplicate values.So I have to group that In such a way that it contains All the Key field with all data merged in Data index of that array.

Here is sample code which I am getting:

```
"Todo": [
        {
            "AreaId": 4,
            "AreaName": "Hall",
            "Sequence": 3,
            "Data": [
                {
                    "AssetId": 2,
                    Some OtherFields,

                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "AreaId": 4,
            "AreaName": "Hall",
            "Sequence": 3,
            "Data": [
                {
                    "AssetId": 3,
                     Some OtherFields,
                }
            ]
        },


        {
                "AreaId": 2,
                "AreaName": "Hall",
                "Sequence": 1,
                "Data": [
                    {
                        "AssetId": 4,
                        Some OtherFields,

                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "AreaId": 2,
                "AreaName": "Hall",
                "Sequence": 1,
                "Data": [
                    {
                        "AssetId": 3,
                         Some OtherFields,
                    }
                ]
            }

]
```

I want this Output to be as mentioned below:

```
 "Todo": [
            {
                "AreaId": 4,
                "AreaName": "Hall",
                "Sequence": 3,
                "Data": [
                    {
                        "AssetId": 2,
                         Some OtherFields,
                    },
                    {
                        "AssetId": 3,
                        Some OtherFields,
                    }

                ]
            },




       {
            "AreaId": 2,
            "AreaName": "Hall",
            "Sequence": 3,
            "Data": [
                {
                    "AssetId": 4,
                     Some OtherFields,
                },
                {
                    "AssetId": 3,
                    Some OtherFields,
                }

            ]
        }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to merge the objects:

We're grouping by AreaId, AreaName and Sequence here, more precisely we're using all other properties apart from Data to group the objects.

For example:

```js
const data = { "Todo": [ { "AreaId": 4, "AreaName": "Hall", "Sequence": 3, "Data": [ { "AssetId": 2, "SomeOtherField1": "Value1", "SomeOtherField2": "Value2" } ] }, { "AreaId": 4, "AreaName": "Hall", "Sequence": 3, "Data": [ { "AssetId": 3, "SomeOtherField1": "Value1", "SomeOtherField2": "Value2" } ] }, { "AreaId": 2, "AreaName": "Hall", "Sequence": 1, "Data": [ { "AssetId": 4, "SomeOtherField1": "Value1", "SomeOtherField2": "Value2" } ] }, { "AreaId": 2, "AreaName": "Hall", "Sequence": 1, "Data": [ { "AssetId": 3, "SomeOtherField1": "Value1", "SomeOtherField2": "Value2" } ] } ] }; 

// Let's do a reduce here..
const result = { Todo: Object.values(data.Todo.reduce((acc, elem ) => {
    // Create a key based on AreaId
    const key = elem.AreaId;
    if (!acc[key]) { 
        acc[key] = { ...elem };
        acc[key].Data = [];
    }
    acc[key].Data = [...(acc[key].Data || []), elem.Data];
    return acc;
}, {}))};

console.log("Result:", result);
```

Comment: Actually this is within some other array.It's Nested array. First there is output array under which lies a index Todo ,which further contains an index Data and I want to merge this Data index based on AreaId property.

Comment: It should be very similar code..we just switch the key to AreaId. If ToDo is an array entry rather than an object property this should not change the code very much either!